# Can I use Redemption without Outlook installed on the server to check email of another account?

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

This one is killing me.

I'm trying to make a simple console app that brings down attachments from an Exchange mailbox.  I tried WebDav originally and that worked fine except that the server is configured to block XML files which makes it useless to me. I can not get the server admins to change any settings at their end.

So I have these questions:

1.) Can I run Redemption on a server without Outlook installed?

2.) Can I use redemption to create a 'temporary' profile? This app will be running under a separate account than that of the mailbox, so I need to be able to specify the mail user/password at runtime (or at least hardcoded into the source).

I have tried messing around with installing the MAPI subsystem and the Perfmon2.exe tool, but when I try and create a new profile it just does nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redemption does not require Outlook, but it uses Extended MAPI. You can download and install [MAPI and CDO from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e).

Redemption has functions to add and remove profiles so you should be able to create a *temporary* profile. Basically, Redemption gives you access to Extended MAPI using COM.

Comment: I havent attempted this yet but I guess it answers my question. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Can you give a code example of creating an email with Redemption (without outlook installed) ?